# SQL where statement with filter options based on a mix

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure code:

```
DECLARE @iscanceled bit
DECLARE @ishired bit
DECLARE @inprocess bit

SELECT 
    e.name,
    e.iscanceled,
    e.ishired
    * 
FROM 
    employee e
```

So the above filters will have to filter the data so if `@iscanceled` and `@ishired` are true, then I have to get all employees canceled and hired.

If `@iscanceled` and `@ishired` and `@inprocess` are true then I have to return all employees canceled and hired and the rest.

If `@iscanceled` is false and `@ishired` and `@inprocess` are true then I have to return all hired and rest but no canceled... and so on.

What is the simplest way to do it?

Comment: For SO specific pointers, start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For a good overview, along with some tools to help you get help, go here: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a value to your parameter, you need to assign 1 if you want to set it to true; if false set to 0. Then if that parameter is not included in your where condition, then assign a value of null. Then in your where clause you do this.

```
WHERE ( iscanceled = @iscanceled OR @iscanceled is null) 
AND  (ishired = @ishired OR @ishired is null)
```

In this way, the statement is still true either you pass a value or you set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

Following query should work for your case.

```
DECLARE @iscanceled bit
DECLARE @ishired bit
DECLARE @inprocess bit

 SELECT 
    e.name,
    e.iscanceled,
    e.ishired,
    * FROM employee e
WHERE (@iscanceled=1 AND @ishired=1 AND @inprocess=1) --RETURNS ALL
     OR (e.iscanceled=@iscanceled AND e.ishired =@ishire)
```